# Run python script from an AppleScript App

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, applescript

I'm wondering if it's possible to run the script below from or inside an **AppleScript App**.

The idea behind all this, is that people would not need to run and deal with the code, say they won't need to run it from **SublimeText** or so, instead just click an app and let the script run and to the job. If that make sens to you ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

class_1 = {"class": "productsPicture"}
class_2 = {"class": "product_content"}
class_3 = {"class": "id-fix"}

# map a column number to the required find parameters
class_to_find = {
0 : class_3,    # Not defined in question
1 : class_1,    
2 : class_1,
3 : class_3,    # Not defined in question
4 : class_2, 
5 : class_2}

with open('urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:
reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
writer = csv.writer(results)

for row in reader:
    # get the url

    output_row = []

    for index, url in enumerate(row):
        url = url.strip()

        # Skip any empty URLs
        if len(url):
            #print('col: {}\nurl: {}\nclass: {}\n\n'.format(index, url, class_to_find[index]))

            # fetch content from server

            try:
                html = requests.get(url).content
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                output_row.extend([url, '', 'bad url'])
                continue
            except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema as e:
                output_row.extend([url, '', 'missing http...'])
                continue

            # soup fetched content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


            divTag = soup.find("div", class_to_find[index])

            if divTag:
                # Return all 'a' tags that contain an href
                for a in divTag.find_all("a", href=True):
                    url_sub = a['href']

                    # Test that link is valid
                    try:
                        r = requests.get(url_sub)
                        output_row.extend([url, url_sub, 'ok'])
                    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                        output_row.extend([url, url_sub, 'bad link'])
            else:
                output_row.extend([url, '', 'no results'])      

    writer.writerow(output_row)
```

Comment: How do you currently invoke the python script? Do you run something similar to: `python path/to/the/python-script.py` via your CLI tool ?

Comment: @RobC I'm just running it from SublimeText app, It does the job, but there's all this code which regular people don't need to be seeing it. Make sens ?

Comment: Does it also run successfully if you **1.** Open "Terminal" application on macOS and **2.** Type `python path/to/the/python-script.py` and hit the return key? (The `path/to/the/python-script.py` part should be the replaced with the actual path to the `.py` file)

Comment: @RobC not really :( Maybe I'm doing something wrong. It says no `No such file or directory: 'urls.csv'`

Comment: If you're unsure how to obtain the path to the file you can: **1.** Open a new _Terminal_ window. **2.** Type `python ` (with trailing space). **3.** Drag and drop the `.py` file from the `Finder` into the _Terminal_ window - the actual path to the file will be auto added to the _Terminal_ window. **4.** Then type return to run it..... If that works then the _answer_ provided in my last comment should work for running via _AppleScript_ too.

Comment: If trying the method in my last comment works successfully, (i.e. running it via the _Terminal_) then let me know what the path part is and I'll provide a formal answer for running via _AppleScript_ for you if you'd like me to. Just let me know.

Comment: @RobC still get that error mentioned above `No such file or directory: 'urls.csv'`  Might be that it's not specified inside actual python code the location of that urls.csv file ?  so it should be something like /path/to/urls.csv inside python in order to run it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172039/discussion-between-robc-and-anotheruser31).

Comment: I recommend using something like [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to create a GUI app wrapper for your shell script. Far easier and much more capable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open *AppleScript Editor* on macOS.
2. In a new window add the following two lines of code:

   ```
   set desktop_folder to "$HOME/Desktop"
   do shell script "python " & desktop_folder & "/Pricematch/foo.py"
   ```

   *Note:* This assumes the `foo.py` file is saved to a folder named *Pricemacth* which exists in the users *Desktop* folder. You'll need to replace the `foo.py` part with the actual real filename.

   Because the `desktop_folder` variable is set to `"$HOME/Desktop"` you should be able to roll this out to multiple users without any issues. You just need to make sure the folder named *Pricematch* is located in their *Desktop* folder and it contains the `.py` file to be run. The `$HOME` part will automatically assume the *User* folder, so you won't need to specify different usernames for each user.

   If you decide to change the location of `.py` you'll need to update the path in the AppleScript accordingly.
3. To save the AppleScript:

   - select *File* > *Save As* from the menu bar.
   - Choose *File Format* > *Application*
   - Enter a filename. E.g. `run-python-script.app`
   - Click `Save` button. (it can be saved in any folder location)
4. Double click `run-python-script.app` in the `Finder` to run it.

---

**EDIT**

In response to the comment:

> is it possible to somehow get a notification when python script finished he's job.

Here's a couple of suggestions - it assumes the python script returns a zero/success exit status. You could try changing line two in the *AppleScript* to:

1. For displaying a dialog message:

   ```
   do shell script "python " & desktop_folder & "/Pricematch/foo.py && osascript -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to activate' -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to display dialog \"Finished Python Script\"'"
   ```
2. Or, for speaking something:

   ```
   do shell script "python " & desktop_folder & "/Pricematch/foo.py && osascript -e 'set Volume 4' -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to say \"Finished!\"' -e 'set Volume 0'"
   ```

Comment: almost there ! I got this error when running the app `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Pricematch/PriceMatcher.py", line 29, in <module>
    with open('/Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Pricematch/urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` this is how the line 29 is looking right now `with open('/Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Pricematch/urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:`

Comment: it worked fine in Terminal, printed what I was expected. The `lineterminator='\n'` got me this : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Pricematch/PriceMatcher.py", line 29, in <module>
    with open('/Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Pricematch/urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', lineterminator='\n') as results:
TypeError: 'lineterminator' is an invalid keyword argument for this function (1)`

Comment: Ok, try the following: **1** Revert `.py` file to to original code. **2** In _Terminal_ type `which python` and take note of the path returned (should be something like this: `/usr/bin/python`) **3.** Change line two in the _AppleScript_ to  `do shell script "/usr/bin/python " & desktop_folder & "/Pricematch/foo.py"` - Note the addition of `/usr/bin/python` instead of just `do shell script "python " & ...`- this part should be the same as  the value returned from running the `which python` command.

Comment: Also worth trying to set line 2 of the _AppleScript_ to: `do shell script "/usr/bin/env python  " & desktop_folder & "/Pricematch/foo.py"`

Comment: you're so close ! I got an error saying this : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Pricematch/PriceMatcher.py", line 29, in <module>
    with open('/Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Pricematch/urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'results.csv' (1)` basically we need to allow it to save that file, right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172060/discussion-between-robc-and-anotheruser31).

Comment: It's working ! My bad ! one more thing, is it possible to somehow get a notification when python script finished he's job ? like a sound notification or text maybe ? it is a part of applescript here or python ? Thank you !

Comment: I had to specify where to find python like you stated. thank you. I just used this in an automator folder action that then starts running some image processing on my iP Cameras. ```/opt/anaconda3/bin/python``` worked