# How can I automate a python script so that it runs everytime i drag a file into a certain folder (on mac)

Tags: python, macos, automation

I made a program so that every time I run it, it changes and arranges the files by name in a specific folder, but I would like this python script to run every time I drag a file into the folder, I have read some about some programs to automate stuff, but i have not been able to find anything helpful.

Comment: Because it's on MacOS, then I would have a look at a cron-job to search for new files inside of the folder. You should be able to make it look in the folder each minute, and should then be able to launch further scripts to handle the files in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Folders actions` to tie an scpt script on `file is added` action of your directory.
Inside that script, you can run your Python script.

Look [here](https://www.lifewire.com/use-os-x-folder-actions-to-know-2260158) to get more info about `Folders actions`
And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598520/run-python-script-from-an-applescript-app) to understand how you can invoke a Python script from an scpt script

Another way is to use [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch)